# Scala flatten a Seq[Future[Seq[]]]

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm stuck trying to flatten a `Seq[Seq[]]` with returning the outcome. So what I had was this:

```
 def getListsByLC(lcId: Int): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    listRepo.getListsByLC(lcId).flatMap { lists =>
      val items: Seq[Future[Seq[Item]]] = lists.map { list =>
        itemRepo.getItemsByList(list.id)
      }
      Future.sequence(items).map { result =>
        Ok(Json.obj("lists" -> lists, "items" -> result))
      }
    }
  }
```

The outcome was obviously an `array` of `arrays`
[image]

Now what I wanted to do is `flatten` this `Future.sequence` in order to only have one array containing all items. This, alongside similar versions I found browsing the web, is what I tried:

```
def getListsByLC(lcId: Int): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    listRepo.getListsByLC(lcId).flatMap { lists =>
      val items: Seq[Future[Seq[Item]]] = lists.map { list =>
        itemRepo.getItemsByList(list.id)
      }
      Future.sequence(items).map(._flatten) { result =>
        Ok(Json.obj("lists" -> lists, "items" -> result))
      }
    }
  }
```

Here I get this compiling error:
[image]
Sorry for the quality of the screenshot. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given your screenshot it looks like your example doesn't compile. What generated the output you posted?

Comment: My first code example generated the output

Comment: Then you should have posted the screenshot that generated the output. Not something that doesn't compile.

Comment: Did you read my question? The first code is what generates the output. This however leaves me with `arrays` inside and an `array` the second code is exactly what you see in the second screenshot, which doesn't compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `_.flatten` instead of `._flatten` and you're missing an additional `.map` call after flattening the sequences:

```
Future.sequence(items).map(_.flatten).map { result =>
    Ok(Json.obj("lists" -> lists, "items" -> result))
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried too, but it says for the second `map`: `Cannot resolve symbol map`

Comment: @Nocebo Your `flatten` call has an additional error.

Comment: @Nocebo Happens :)